# How can I access the Phone’s Internal Storage over WiFi bypassing the "Client Isolation"?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-transfer

[This](https://www.xda-developers.com/easily-access-your-phones-internal-storage-over-wifi/) article explains the approach of using wifi to access the phone's files. However, both devices MUST be using the same wifi provided by a router.

Now I am using a public wifi, which needs to be accessed by login. This wifi provider told me:

**As it is a public WiFi system we implement something called "Client Isolation". This security implementation prevents communication between devices on the same network. Without this, anyone connected to the WiFi could access your devices. Unfortunately it is not something we can turn off as it would jeopardize the security of other users of the WiFi network.**

So is there an alternative that I can still access my phone under public wifi?

The phone is Android, and my PC is Win 10.

I feel bluetooth is not sensitive and stable enough.

I know there are software like dropbox, but it takes too much time.

Comment: You would have to go the way over the internet. So you would need a server where you implement a solution yourself or you would need to use cloud services like Dropbox. Another option would be to use bluetooth. What OS on the phone and on the Computer are you using?

Comment: It is Android, and my PC is Win 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I had an Android phone I used [airdroid](https://www.airdroid.com) which was pretty good. I could then access everything on the phone via a web app. It is pretty similar to iCloud. This would work even via mobile network.

Comment: thank you very much, yes, it can!

Answer (score 0):

What do you need my friend it's a daemon on each devices could be ssh in both there are a bunch of apps capable to do so like sshelper on android devices and filezilla for windows in that way you can send and pull files from the android devices from Windows and if you like to do in the other way pull and push files from the andorid devices to the windows computer you can se the filezilla server on windows and use an app like ES explorer in android i hope this info redirect to you to do what do you need !

Comment: Thank you! It seems that airdroid can do this!